# How can I update the content from a rails app in all devices being used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, websocket

I really don't have a clue on how to do this. So when admin, deletes or adds a posts, I want people who are viewing the app to automatically see the new content without them having to refresh. I researched and some say websockets. But is there any other way to do this? or What is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, what you are looking for is websocket.
The app will "subscribe" users to a channel (which can be attached to a page for example). 
Then you create events for this channel, in your case:

```
 - when an admin create a post, create a create_post event
 - when an admin  delete a post, create a delete_post event
```

Then, you can trigger actions when a new event is created.
When a delete_post event is created, hide the post in the page. When a create_post event is created, append it.

You have multiple solutions for this. Rails 5 includes ActionCable, which is a websocket "system" integrated into rails ([Here is a tutorial](https://medium.com/@dhh/rails-5-action-cable-demo-8bba4ccfc55e)).
Or you have external solutions, such as [pusher](https://pusher.com/).

Comment: I have a rails app that displays a list where people sign into the list through a form. But there aren't any users, except admin which can delete the people in the list. So I want the list to update in all devices when the someone adds or gets deleted from the list. Is it still with web sockets? and thank you for responding.

Comment: If you don't want the page to be reloaded and that people can see in realtime who's on the list, yes it can be done with websockets

Comment: But thats with rails 5.0 I still dont have that yet

Comment: That's why I also wrote about Pusher, which is an API based websocket